# getting control reaches end of non-void function from hcf function

Tags: c

```
int hcf (int a, int b) {
            int gcd;
    
            for (int i = 0; i <= a && i <= b; i++) {
                   if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
                   gcd = i;
                   return gcd;
                  }
            }
}
```

..\src\lcm-using-recursion.c: In function 'hcf':
..\src\lcm-using-recursion.c:41:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

```
           41 | }
              | ^
```

Comment: What if `a` or `b` is negative?

Comment: in some condition return statement will not be reached - you need to add something at the end of the function

Comment: initially gcd=-1 and instead of return you should use break inside loop and finally retunr gcd at end of function

Answer (score 0):

The function that you created should always return an int

Reaching the end of a non-void function means that has undefined behaviour

Here is a function that would be valid, it would return -1 if nothing is found

```
int hcf (int a, int b) { 
        int gcd;

        for (int i = 0; i <= a && i <= b; i++) {
               if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
               gcd = i;
               return gcd;
              }
        }
        return -1;
}
```

edit: small changes after a comment

Comment: "_Reaching the end of a non-void function means that a path can lead to a return of the wrong type._" Not really - it means the program is invalid and has undefined behaviour. So the program could blow up your toaster or somehow work OK or anything possibly.

Answer (score 0):

This function has to return some int -- that's the compiler error here.

However there are many other issues.

- the gcd of two coprime numbers is 1, by definiton. If a and b are coprime then the `return` in the for loop is never encountered.
- the return in the for loop is never encountered for negative a or b either, as tkausl points out
- even if the loop runs, there's a bug in it. For any `a>=0` and `b>=0` you're going to return 1 when `i = 1`, because `a % 1 == 0 && b % 1 == 0` is always true.

```c
int hcf (int a, int b) {
            int gcd;
    
            for (int i = 0; i <= a && i <= b; i++) {
                   if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) { /* <<< wrong <<< */
                   gcd = i;
                   return gcd;
                  }
            }

            // a and b have no common divisor
            return 1;
}
```